# waitFor in Jest doesn't wait for setTimeOut no matter how long

Tags: babel-jest

I'm using Formik to create a form for a React web app. The submission is as the following code.

```js
  const submitForm = (values) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));

    setFormStatus(status.loading);

    // handle request.
    axios
      .put("#", values)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Submission Success");
        setFormStatus(status.success);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log(`Submission Failure`);
        setFormStatus(status.failure);
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("Submission CleanUp");
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("Neutralizing Form");
          setFormStatus(status.neutral);
          // tell to animate.
          setSwitchSubmitBtn(!switchSubmitBtn);
        }, 2000);
      });
  };
```

After the axis request, there will be a 2s delay before I set the `status` state back to neutral.

However, I'm testing using **Jest**, `waitFor` doesn't work as expected. The timeout in submission seems blocked, as no matter how long I wait for the submission, it just won't occur. I found a solution to this by using `jest.advanceTimer`, but adding the same amount of delay in `waitFor` doesn't work.

```js
  it("INPUT_FORM_TC_008", async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    render(<InputForm />);
    axios.put.mockImplementation(async () => {
      console.log("MOCKED PUT");
      return Promise.reject();
    });

    // click submit Button
    user.click(screen.getByTestId("submitBtn"));
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.queryByTestId("crossIcon")).not.toBeNull();
    });
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(2000);
    });
    await waitFor(() => {
      // crossIcon will be unmounted once `status` changes to neutral.
      expect(screen.queryByTestId("crossIcon")).toBeNull();
    });
  });
```

The following code won't work if I don't use `jest.advanceTimer`, even I set timeout much longer than the one in submission.

```
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.queryByTestId("crossIcon")).toBeNull();
    }, 5000);
```

I suspect that this is related to the event loop stuff, but I tried to set the timeout to be `20ms` in the submission and it works. So I looking for a reason why this happens.

I tried to test a state change using `setTimeOut` using Jest. I expect after the amount of time I specified in `setTimeOut` the state should be changed. But using `waitFor` won't work even set a longer timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting a setTimeout in a scope that is immediately exited. This code should still work when it's actually run due to a closure on your function, but in Jest the test will say, "welp, looks like there's no more synchronous code" and finish the test before waiting for the execution.

If you want more information on why setTimeout behaves this way you can check the MDN article here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

But putting it very simply, it uses something called the "event loop" which is how JS handles asynchronous code while still being a synchronous language. When you use setTimeout, you're simply adding the function execution to the event loop and saying, "Don't execute this code now, run other code until the 2000 ms have gone by, then run this code." Which works fine in your implementation because you're allowing 2000ms to go by. But Jest doesn't wait, it just says "There's no more code to execute and nothing is ready in the event loop, the test must be complete" and cleaning everything up immediately.

You could resolve this by wrapping your setTimeout in a promise, like:

```js
  //........
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Submission CleanUp");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Neutralizing Form");
        resolve(status.neutral);
      }, 2000);
    })
  });
```

Then have your actual implementation code wait for the promise to resolve and set your formStatus and submissionButton states after the Promise is resolved. This would be a simpler API, would allow for greater abstraction, and would make testing easier since you'd now be able to wait for this execution to finish with a `.then()` block in your tests as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Based on your hints, I realized I used `await waitFor` API wrong. `await waitFor(()=>{}, {timeout: 2000})` this would work, I have to wrap timeout into an `option` object. I still wonder why putting `setTimeOut` into a promise can provide a simpler API, and how to test it using `then` as the submission Function is inside the component.

Comment: Great, if this reply helped you then please mark it as the answer. For more context, the `await` keyword will only work in an async function, and it will lock synchronous execution (no other code but waiting can happen for 2 full seconds) so may not be the best approach, but glad you got the specific problem figured out

Comment: If you return a Promise from a `.then()` block, you can chain an additional `.then()` block onto your implementation which will execute when the Promise resolves. This is called Promise chaining and is a pretty common design pattern. This article has your specific use case in detail: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#returning-promises